# I want to find the maximum value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an age table with an attribute named age, I want to find the maximum value:

[image]

of attribute data. I asked how to find the maximum value in the age table and then displayed it into the agricultural polytechnic of samarinda country

[image]

Comment: Please write your code in `code block` and not as a picture.

Comment: Yes thank you suggesting other times not I repeat

Answer (score 0):

Please try below message

**Try below code:**

```
Umur::max('id')
```

You can pass the passed parameter inside the Max function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$max = YourModelName::max('id');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#aggregates